# why aws lambda doesn't have aws java sdk enviroment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

HI i maven packaged my java application with dependencies and uploaded it to aws lambda and ran. it smoothly worked.

but now i exclude my dependencies and still upload it to aws lambda and run it:

the lambda tells me error as below

```
    START RequestId: fd2040a3-6a86-11e6-bba5-f75cd41a0da7 Version: $LATEST
Error loading class augury.api.SaveAuguryApi: com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDB: class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDB
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more

END RequestId: fd2040a3-6a86-11e6-bba5-f75cd41a0da7
REPORT RequestId: fd2040a3-6a86-11e6-bba5-f75cd41a0da7  Duration: 0.29 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 47 MB
```

I'm curious why there's no java aws sdk environment available in aws lambda ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why. But

for [nodejs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-java-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)

```
Note
The Lambda service has preinstalled the AWS SDK for Node.js.
```

same with [Python](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html).

There's no notification saying lambda service preinstalled aws sdk for [Java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-java-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)